# Method invocation cause ClassCastException when run a test

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

I'm trying to run some test in one fragment that extends of some parents... My problem is that I have one method that is doing a cast with one Activity class.

`FragmentToTest` `extends` `ParentNotification` that `extends` from `ParentFragment`.

This is the method that I have in ParentFragment:

```
public Location getCurrentLocation(){
        return ((ParentLocationActivity) getActivity()).getCurrentLocation();
    }
```

Then, when I run my test I get this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity cannot be cast to com.myproject.activity.ParentLocationActivity
```

If I return, for example, nothing. I can run the test perfectly. But I need to test y fragment with this method.

My question is; is some way to fix the error from the test or is some way to can do invisible this method from my testing class or something similar to skip this method??

Notice that this method (getCurrentLocation()) works fine in whole application when is required.

Thanks in advance

This is my test class:

```
public class CreateOfferPresenterTest extends FragmentActivity {


    @Rule
    public FragmentTestRule<?, CreateOfferFragment> fragmentTestRule = FragmentTestRule.create(CreateOfferFragment.class);


    @Test
    public void setUp(){
    }
```

}

Comment: does ParentLocationActivity extend FragmentActivity?

Comment: ParentLocationActivity extends of AppCompatActivity

Comment: @Nilu Yes, ParentLocationActivity are extending of AppCompatActivity

Comment: @Nilu Sorry I don't understand you before. Yep, I've extends the test case in the two ways and I get this error: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: @Nilu I've updated my test class. As you can see is only two lines. Where do you want that I try your last suggestion inside the Before in the test?

Answer (score 0):

The error message of

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity cannot be cast to
>   com.myproject.activity.ParentLocationActivity

tells you that you had an `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity` object and could not cast it to `com.myproject.activity.ParentLoationActivity`. If you intend to downcast, you will need to make sure that `ParentLocationActivity` is extended from `FragmentActivity` directly or transitively. Otherwise, you will need to implement a method which will creaye your `ParentLocationActivity` as you need it based on the `FragmentActivity` and do the casting yourself via the source-code you write.